# Apache reverse proxy with glassfish and openfire

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I'm attempting to use apache as a front end with glassfish and openfire. My httpd.conf config is this:

```
ProxyPass /proxy http://localhost:7070/http-bind/
ProxyPassReverse /proxy http://localhost:7070/http-bind/

ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8080/app
ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:8080/app
```

This is working fine for me so far, `domain.com/app` connects to my glassfish server, and `domain.com/proxy` connects to my openfire server.

What I really want, is for the URL to be `domain.com` and direct the user to glassfish, but for `domain.com/proxy` to still direct to openfire.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this not work? I think the proxy pass directives are parsed in order so as long as you have the more specific case first you should be ok.

```
ProxyPass /proxy http://localhost:7070/http-bind/
ProxyPassReverse /proxy http://localhost:7070/http-bind/

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/app
```

Mentioned here:

http://www.2020media.com/blog/2010/02/excluding-directories-in-ajp-proxypass/

Comment: doh.  I feel kinda dumb now.  http://localhost:8080/app didn't work, but http://localhost:8080/app/ (with trailing slash) does.